# Как увеличить количество запросов к серверу за минимальное время?

Tags: c#, .net

Как увеличить количество запросов к серверу за минимальное время?
Здравствуйте, сразу прошу извинить за свою тупость(Только начинаю учить c#), но написать данную программу очень сильно нужно. Проблема в том что я отправляю на сервер запрос:

```
private string GET(string Url)
{
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Url);
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    string Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    return Out;
}
```

Но мне не нравиться скорость выполнения моей программы. За 10 секунд у меня получается максимально отправить только 20 запросов на разные страницы сайта. Я так понимаю это происходит так:

1. Программа отправляет запрос.
2. Ждем какое то время пока сервер ответит нам(вот тут и самое сложное место, я так думаю)
3. Обрабатывает ответ.
4. Возвращаемся на 1 шаг.

Я правильно понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста?
Возможно ли сделать так:

1. Программа отправляет запрос на 1 страницу.
2. Программа отправляет запрос на 2 страницу.
3. Ждем какое то время пока сервер ответит нам на 1 страницу.
4. Ждем какое то время пока сервер ответит нам на 2 страницу.
5. Обрабатываем ответы.

Есть предположения что для этого нужно использовать потоки... Если не сложно с кодом пожалуйста объясните. Заранее Огромное Спасибо.

Comment: Как ты запросы отправляешь?

Comment: Да, через потоки, но эту тему нужно изучать. День, 2.

Answer (score 2):

Ты используешь синхронный метод `GetResponse()` который ожидает получение данных от удалённого сервера. Вместо него ты можешь использовать асинхронный метод [`GetResponseAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync(v=vs.110).aspx) или в старом варианте [`BeginGetResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetrequeststream(v=vs.110).aspx) с указанием callback'а при получении ответа. Таким образом ты можешь отправить запросы хоть сотне страниц, не порождая дополнительные потоки в момент вызова (ответы будут обработаны в потоках из пула).